# apt update Proxy Error

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

How to resolve

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  502  Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ) [IP: 10.10.8.118 8080]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  502  Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ) [IP: 10.10.8.118 8080]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  502  Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ) [IP: 10.10.8.118 8080]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  502  Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ) [IP: 10.10.8.118 8080]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  502  Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ) [IP: 10.10.8.118 8080]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  502  Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ) [IP: 10.10.8.118 8080]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This question also got closed voted by a reviewer for being unclear. Why I don't know because it is certainly not an unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  502  Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ) [IP: 10.10.8.118 8080]
> ```

This indicates that your proxy server denied you access to this URL. This is not a problem with Ubuntu. It's a problem with your proxy server, probably run by your company or school.

You need to contact the administrator for the proxy server, and ask if they can open for Ubuntu mirrors for you.